# Where do I find the icons / animations recommended in the Windows 7 UX guide?

Tags: windows, windows-7, icons, user-experience

The Windows 7 UX guide has nice illustrations and examples of icons, but I really can't find them in the SDK. Are they hiding somewhere, or are they not available ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about the common UI icons, then you are supposed to get them programmatically. For instance, you can use

```
var
  errIcon: HICON;
begin
  errIcon := LoadIcon(0, IDI_ERROR);
  DrawIcon(Canvas.Handle, 10, 10, errIcon),
```

(Delphi code) to draw an error icon.

[image: Windows UI standard icons]

See [`LoadIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072(VS.85).aspx), [`DrawIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648064(VS.85).aspx) at MSDN. You might also wish to study [`STATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760767(VS.85).aspx) controls.

To draw other visual elements, you need to use the visual themes API, e.g. the [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289(VS.85).aspx) function that accepts a class, part, and state and then draws it:

[image: Chevron]

Comment: What about the chevron examples, which are used expander controls (and in WPF as well)?

Comment: @Mmarquee: You have to use the visual theme functions for that: See my Q and A at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009701/windows-visual-themes-gallery-of-parts-and-states.

Comment: Great, this looks exactly what I need. Cheers Andreas

Answer (score 1):

[SHGetStockIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a decent list of system icons.

Comment: Nearly, but this still doesn't have the rounded chevron. I'm lost as to where it lives.

Comment: @Mmarquee: I thought I told you? You need [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289(VS.85).aspx). Have a look at the `TASKDIALOG` class, the `TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON` part, and the `TDLGEBS_NORMAL` state. See [this image](http://privat.rejbrand.se/chevron.png).