# Chevron button in delphi dialog form

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7

I want to draw a Chevron button

[image]

in a custom dialog form and I'm wondering if exist a State  and Part constant to be used with the [DrawThemeBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or I must draw this kind of button manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest I can find for XP is

`ThemeServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, GetElementDetails(tebNormalGroupExpandNormal),
    Rect(10, 100, 100, 200));`

[image]

or

`EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND` using DrawThemeBackground directly. However this draws a double arrow (on XP at least)

However later windows versions also have TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON, which is what you want judging by the image at [Where do I find the icons / animations recommended in the Windows 7 UX guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170718/where-do-i-find-the-icons-animations-recommended-in-the-windows-7-ux-guide)

Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282848/andreas-rejbrand) (as usual for theme and customer drawing related questions)

See also his utility at [Windows Visual Themes: Gallery of Parts and States?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009701/windows-visual-themes-gallery-of-parts-and-states)

Ideally I would use the second version if available, but fall back to the first on XP.

Comment: Here's a link to the UXguide: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it in the list of Parts and States? Then it doesn't exist. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(v=vs.85).aspx