# VCL TImage + TImageList, transparent feature doesn't work or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Using Borland C++ Builder 2009

I screen-captured three buttons from a W7 Windows dialog and put them in a TImageList.  I load the 3 variants in a TImage, when appropriate.

```
Image->Picture->Bitmap = NULL ; // Clear previous state
ImageList->GetBitmap(2, Image->Picture->Bitmap) ;
```

PS: `Image->Transparent = True`

On Windows 7 and Windows 10 this seems to work properly.
BUT I just realized, only because the TForm the TImage is placed on has the exact same background `color`.  (confirmed not to work after I changed the background to lime)

On Windows XP the button doesn't look so great.  Since XP seems to have slightly different background color.  Mind you, it's also `clBtnFace`

XP: [image: XP]
.         .    .    Windows 7: [image: Windows 7]

I have also experimented with setting `BlendColor` and `DrawingStyle` of the TImageList control, combined with `Image->Transparent = true` or `false`.

But I can't get it to work.

I captured the `Image->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->Pixels[0][0]` value on W7 and put it in `ImageList->BlendColor` (`ImageList->DrawingStyle = dsFocus` or `dsSelected`) and so forth, without success.

I also have experimented with explicitly setting `Image->Transparent = True` again after a `ImageList->GetBitmap(2, Image->Picture->Bitmap)` and even tried

```
Image->Picture->Bitmap->TransparentColor =
Image->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->Pixels[0][0]
```

without a noticeable effect.

Your thoughts ?

Comment: You need the original glyph, with the alpha channel. Screen cap after render is too late.

Comment: Have you tried to modify your image by hand and insert one pixel of `clFuchsia` color in the upper left corner of the image?

Comment: @Wodzu It won't help because these images rely on partial alpha levels to look good

Comment: Instead of capture the image from the screen you can try drawing the expand button using the [`DrawThemeBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289(VS.85).aspx) method passing the `TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON` part and one of the valid states (`TDLGEBS_NORMAL`, `TDLGEBS_HOVER`, `TDLGEBS_PRESSED`, etc)

Comment: I see ... thanks for the comments !  Any idea if this glyph can be found on a W7 system and where ?  @RRUZ, seems to be limited to Vista and up and the issue I'm having is with XP

Comment: @Peter for XP try the `EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND` part like is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264484/chevron-button-in-delphi-dialog-form

Comment: @RRUZ could you answer with a code example ?  I'm confused as to what function to use, and what to pass to the function exactly ?  Also how to show the different states (which is why I have 3 bitmaps, one for every state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I said on my comment instead of capture the image from the screen you can try drawing the expand button using the [`DrawThemeBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289(VS.85).aspx) method passing the `TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON` part and one of the valid states (`TDLGEBS_NORMAL`, `TDLGEBS_HOVER`, `TDLGEBS_PRESSED`, etc) . And for Windows XP you can use `EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND` part  and one of these states (`EBHC_NORMAL`, `EBHC_HOT`, `EBHC_PRESSED`)

Check this sample which drawn the *expando button*  in a TImage.

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Vsstyle.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color = clBtnFace;
  Image1->Canvas->FillRect(Image1->ClientRect);

  OSVERSIONINFO verwin;
  verwin.dwOSVersionInfoSize=sizeof(verwin);
  if (GetVersionEx(&verwin))
  {
    //Check  the Windows version
    if (verwin.dwMajorVersion >= 6) // is Vista at least?
    {
      HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_TASKDIALOG);
      if (hTheme)
      {
          SIZE s;
          //get the size of the  TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON
          if (GetThemePartSize(hTheme, Image1->Canvas->Handle, TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON, TDLGEBS_NORMAL, NULL, TS_TRUE, &s) == S_OK)
          {
              TRect pRect = Rect(0, 0, s.cx, s.cy);
              DrawThemeBackground(hTheme, Image1->Canvas->Handle, TDLG_EXPANDOBUTTON, TDLGEBS_NORMAL, &pRect, NULL);
           }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_EXPLORERBAR);
      if (hTheme)
      {
          SIZE s;
          //get the size of the  EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND
          if (GetThemePartSize(hTheme, Image1->Canvas->Handle, EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND, EBHC_NORMAL, NULL, TS_TRUE, &s) == S_OK)
          {
              TRect pRect = Rect(0, 0, s.cx, s.cy);
              DrawThemeBackground(hTheme, Image1->Canvas->Handle, EBP_NORMALGROUPEXPAND, EBHC_NORMAL, &pRect, NULL);
           }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!  I'm going to try this on Monday (can't right now, no access to my 'stuff').  
Question, what size/dimensions should Image1 have ?  Or doesn't it matter ?  Other settings that are important ?  Transparent ?  Stretch ? ...

Comment: Just drop a TImage with the default values.

Comment: Making progress !  Thanks !!  For completeness you may add that (at least for my Borland C++ Builder 2009) version you also need to include: `#include <UxTheme.hpp>` and add `UxTheme.lib` to the project !
Also, a link to where you get the image values from would be nice.  I'm looking right now for the UP pointing version of the glyph, for my code !

Comment: For the other states I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I have it working **very nicely** now !  Thanks for your help @RRUZ !

Comment: PS. I **did** set `Image1->Transparent = true` to get the desired transparent effect (just for completeness)