# Is it possible to determine the font face/size/colour used by DrawThemeText?

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts

The Windows API has the [DrawThemeText Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773312(v=vs.85).aspx) for drawing text to a rectangle in the style of a certain [part and state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(v=vs.85).aspx) according to the specified [Windows theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759821(v=vs.85).aspx). (Andreas Rejbrand made a [neat application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009701/windows-visual-themes-gallery-of-parts-and-states) demonstrating parts and states.)

Is it possible to determine what font face, size and colour is used for a given part and state?

[GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used to find out about only some system fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bevy of GetThemeXxxx() functions.  You're probably looking for, respectively, GetThemeFont(), GetThemeMetric() and GetThemeColor().  The metric one was a bit of a guess, there are several other sizing related ones.  GetThemeFont also returns the font size.  [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486120%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the MSDN library.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how I missed all those functions. Cheers.

Comment: GetThemeFont() and GetThemeColor() are indeed the functions to use. The former will return the font face/size/weight/etc. (it returns a LOGFONT) and the latter will return the font colour given the TMT_TEXTCOLOR property.

Comment: I ended up writing a bit about this here: http://blog.quppa.net/2011/04/30/windows-theme-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to track down a single working example of GetThemeFont, let alone the managed version of VisualStyleRenderer.GetThemeFont. Examining the Mono source yields a comment by the author that they also could not get GetThemeFont to return anything but null.

Use of TMT_FONT consistently throws an unmanaged memory error and use of TMT_GLYPHFONT consistently returns the 'not supported' error. This particular api appears to be horribly flawed and (dare I say it) non-functional.

The reply marked as an answer isn't an answer at all. The author asked how to drive and you pointed him at a car that wouldn't start.

Comment: I've added a test in the form of a gist to show that the managed wrapper for GetThemeFont, VisualStyleRenderer.GetFont, doesn't return a non-null value for any of the VisualStyleElements https://gist.github.com/1219126. If you examine the method using Reflector, you'll see how they handle GetThemeFont in a managed environment - not that it matters much.

Comment: I've posted a WPF sample here: http://blog.quppa.net/2011/10/24/windows-theme-fonts-redux-sample-code/