# Visual Style for Windows Explorer hover and selection

Tags: winapi, themes, visual-styles

The last three versions of Windows have all had translucent highlight and hover effects in Windows Explorer listview:

[image]

Using [a theme explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009712/12597) I see that the ListItem has no state that matches what i see in Windows:

[image]

Is there a:

- class
- part
- state

that represents the ListView in Windows?

Comment: That's probably an issue with "theme explorer". The listview has to have explorer style to have draw that specific look. It needs `SetWindowTheme(hwnd_listview, L"Explorer", NULL)`.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but do we even know if the explorer "list view" actually *is* a common controls list view control in Windows 7 and later? The window class is simply `DirectUIHWND` these days (black magic).

Comment: @Andreas AFAIK it is a custom control that just mimics some listview behaviour. The theme can still be applied as shown by 1st comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For compatibility reasons ListView still has the old style look by default. `DrawThemeBackground(htheme, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, ...)` will simply draw a solid rectangle with border, for all item states, as shown in above image. `GetSysColor` should be used to get the right colors for this listview.

A call to `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"Explorer", NULL)` will load the new theme data and draw the list items similar to Explorer. Example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"Explorer", NULL);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        auto hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        HTHEME ht = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"LISTVIEW");
        if(ht)
        {
            RECT rc = { 10, 10, 100, 50 };
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_SELECTED, &rc, NULL); OffsetRect(&rc, 0, 55);
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_DISABLED, &rc, NULL); OffsetRect(&rc, 0, 55);
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_SELECTED, &rc, NULL); OffsetRect(&rc, 0, 55);
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_HOT, &rc, NULL); OffsetRect(&rc, 0, 55);
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_HOTSELECTED, &rc, NULL); OffsetRect(&rc, 0, 55);
            DrawThemeBackground(ht, hdc, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_SELECTEDNOTFOCUS, &rc, NULL);
            CloseThemeData(ht);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Output:

[image]