# Does Cocoa have something like WinAPI's DrawThemeBackground (a function that draws native controls)?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Windows API has very powerful functions that allow to draw native controls in all states:

`DrawThemeBackground()`
`DrawThemeText()`

Here's a really nice example of their usage:

[Windows Visual Themes: Gallery of Parts and States?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009701/windows-visual-themes-gallery-of-parts-and-states/4009712#4009712)

Does Cocoa have something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has "soft deprecated" `NSCell` and the various control-specific subclasses, but you can use them for this. You create one, configure its properties, and then tell it to draw in a frame in a view.

Getting the properties just right can be tedious. You might want to create a control of the relevant kind in a test project's view (using IB) and then interrogate its cell's properties programmatically. And/or configure such a control to use a custom subclass of the corresponding cell class which logs which methods are called on it with what parameters in various scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response. I'm very intrigued by the ability to log which methods are called with what parameters. Do you have a link where I can read about this? I don't have much Cocoa experience. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any particular link. I was just suggesting that you override any method about which you want to learn more and log the parameters before calling through to `super`.