# Get system color for group box border

Tags: windows, winapi

Usually most colors used by standard controls can be got from `GetSysColor`, I ran a test with all the `COLOR_` constants (0-30) and compared it to the color of a group box border and none of them matched. I'm using XP, and the colour of the group box border is `0xD0D0BF`.

How do you get the system color used for drawing the group box border?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "Classic" theme (on XP, or the only theme in previous versions of Windows), the group box border is not a single color. It is actually an "etched" line, composed of two lines of different colors. Each of those colors have a `COLOR_*` value, but you don't want to try and recreate the line this way. Instead, use GDI's [`DrawEdge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162477.aspx) function with the `EDGE_ETCHED` flag.

But if you have themes enabled, the group box border actually *is* a single color and that color varies depending on the selected theme. There's no way to retrieve theme colors using `GetSysColor` because they don't have corresponding `COLOR_*` values. That API was invented *long* before themes were conceived. Instead, there's a whole new set of Themes APIs. The one you're interested in here is [`GetThemeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773397.aspx), but in order to use that you'll also need [`OpenThemeData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759821.aspx) and [`CloseThemeData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773287.aspx).

The tricky part is figuring out what to pass to the `OpenThemeData` function. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217532/what-are-the-possible-classes-for-the-openthemedata-function) might help with that. A group box control is actually a special type of button control, so the style you want is:

- Class: `BUTTON`
- Part: `BP_GROUPBOX`
- States: `GBS_NORMAL` (and possibly also `GBS_DISABLED`)
- Property ID: <strike>`TMT_BORDERCOLOR`</strike> ???

Do make sure that your code has proper fallback support for when themes are disabled! Use the [`IsAppThemed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759809.aspx) function to determine that dynamically at runtime and select the appropriate drawing code path.

---

**EDIT:** After some testing on an XP VM, I can't find the right `TMT_*` property ID to specify to get the right color for a group box's border. I'm not sure what's up with that. But you *can* get the border drawn for you using the [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) function:

```
HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(grpBox->m_hWnd, L"Button");
DrawThemeBackground(hTheme, hDC, BP_GROUPBOX, GBS_NORMAL, &rcArea, NULL);
CloseThemeData(hTheme);
```

[image]

Unfortunately, that doesn't tell you how to get the color value itself.

Comment: Thanks for going through so much effort to research this answer (even after I'd already marked it as the answer as well!).

Comment: Apparently there is no direct way to get the color.  I enumerated over all `TMT_*` values, and _none_ of them matched what a group box actually uses.  TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT may be close.

Comment: The problem may be that it is not a single color. For example, if it is a gradient. If `TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT` is close, that might be the explanation. And also help to explain why it is called "hint".